# SwiftUI Why doesn't the Rectangle created in my code fill up the whole page?

Tags: autolayout, swiftui

I'm trying to figure out layout mechanisms in `SwiftUI`, and while its fairly straightforward, I don't know what I'm missing here.

According to me, the following code should fill the device's entire screen with the colour green, but for some reason, it leaves a small gap at the bottom of the screen. This is not the safe area as the gap is left even in older devices such as the iPhone SE.

I know I can achieve the same result just by changing the screen colour to green; as I said I'm trying to figure out layout in `SwiftUI`.

I'd really appreciate any help.

```
struct ContentView: View {
     var body: some View {            
         VStack {
             Green()
              .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
         }
     }
}

struct Green: View {
    let hh = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let ww = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(width: ww, height: hh, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to used UIScreen restriction, instead it needs to use

```
struct Green: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
           .fill(Color.green)
    }
}
```

and area filled completely, `cause detected dynamically. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Rectangle()` inside your `ZStack`. Here is your `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // This is your green background
            Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.green)
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            // Use other UI stuffs here
            VStack {
                Text("Use other UI components here")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `ZStack`. add `Color` direct as a component

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Use other UI components here")
        }
    }
}
```